# Barycenter of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lipschitz-functions, barycentric-coordinates

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space and $\mathcal{F}(X) = \overline{span}(\{ \delta_x : x \in X \})$, where $\delta_X : Lip(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $Lip(X)$ is the set of real-valued Lipschitz functions on $X$.

Define $\beta : \mathcal{F}(X) \rightarrow X$ given by 
$$\beta(\mu) = \int_X x d\mu(x)$$

In this [paper](http://kaltonmemorial.missouri.edu/docs/sm2003c.pdf), before Lemma $2.4$, the author mentioned that $\beta(\mu)$ is the **barycenter of measure $\mu$**.

Question: What is the meaning of barycenter of measure $\mu$ and why the integral gives us the barycenter of measure $\mu$?

Answer (score 4):

It generalizes the barycenter of point sets. Namely, if you have a finite set $\left\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\right\}$ and you look at the average of the Dirac measure $\delta_{p_i}$
$$\mu=\frac{\delta_{p_1}+\ldots+\delta_{p_n}}{n},$$
then obvioulsy $\beta(\mu)$ is the barycenter of $\left\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\right\}$.